# How should I generate the n-th digit of this sequence in logarithmic time complexity?

Tags: c, algorithm, sequence

I have the following problem:

[image: homework problem]

The point (a) was easy, here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 1000000

char conjugateDigit(char digit)
{
    if(digit == '1')
        return '2';
    else
        return '1';
}

void conjugateChunk(char* chunk, char* result, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = conjugateDigit(chunk[i]);
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}

void displaySequence(int n)
{
    // +1 for '\0'
    char result[MAX_DIGITS + 1];

    // In this variable I store temporally the conjugates at each iteration.
    // Since every component of the sequence is 1/4 the size of the sequence
    // the length of `tmp` will be MAX_DIGITS / 4 + the string terminator.
    char tmp[(MAX_DIGITS / 4) + 1];

    // There I assing the basic value to the sequence
    strcpy(result, "1221");

    // The initial value of k will be 4, since the base sequence has ethe length
    // 4. We can see that at each step the size of the sequence 4 times bigger
    // than the previous one.
    for(int k = 4; k < n; k *= 4)
    {
        // We conjugate the first part of the sequence.
        conjugateChunk(result, tmp, k);

        // We will concatenate the conjugate 2 time to the original sequence
        strcat(result, tmp);
        strcat(result, tmp);

        // Now we conjugate the conjugate in order to get the first part.
        conjugateChunk(tmp, tmp, k);

        strcat(result, tmp);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Insert n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("The result is: ");
    displaySequence(n);

    return 0;
}
```

But for the point b I have to generate the `n`-th digit in logarithmic time. I have no idea how to do it. I have tried to find a mathematical property of that sequence, but I failed. Can you help me please? It is not the solution itself that really matters, but how do you tackle this kind of problems in a short amount of time.

This [problem](http://fmi.unibuc.ro/ro/pdf/2014/admitere/Subiecte_admitere_DL_INFO_18iulie2014.pdf) was given last year (in 2014) at the admission exam at the Faculty of Mathematics and Computer Science at the University of Bucharest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you define *d_ij* as the value of the *i*th digit in *s_j*.

Note that for a fixed *i*, *d_ij* is defined only for large enough values of *j* (at first, *s_j* is not large enough).

Now you should be able to prove to yourself the two following things:

- once *d_ij* is defined for some *j*, it will never change as *j* increases (hint: induction).
- For a fixed *i*, *d_ij* is defined for *j* logarithmic in *i* (hint: how does the length of *s_j* increase as a function of *j*?).

Combining this with the first item, which you solved, should give you the result along with the complexity proof.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple programming solution, the key is to use recursion.

Firstly determine the minimal `k` that the length of `s_k` is more than `n`, so that `n`-th digit exists in `s_k`. According to a definition, `s_k` can be split into 4 equal-length parts. You can easily determine into which part the `n`-th symbol falls, and what is the number of this `n`-th symbol within that part --- say that `n`-th symbol in the whole string is `n'`-th within this part. This part is either `s_{k-1}`, either `inv(s_{k-1})`. In any case you recursively determine what is `n'`-th symbol within that `s_{k-1}`, and then, if needed, invert it.

Comment: I don't understand properly your solution. So, I have to find the minimum `k` which is less than n. For example, if `n=10` then `k` will be equal to `16`? Now, in order to find out this information and the position of `n` relative to that sequence I can use the following expression `for(int before = 4, current = 16; current < n; before *= 4, current *= 4);` After this loop `n' = n - before`. But I didn't understand what to do after that. Can you give me more information please? You said something about a recursive call, but what's the function that I should call recursively?

Comment: @cristid9, you got the definition of `k` wrong. You need that `s_k` is longer than `n` symbols. For `n=10` this is `k=2`, as `s_2` has the length of 16, which is `>10`. Now we define function `f(n,k)`, which returns the `n`th symbol in `s_k`. It works the following way. The string `s_k` consists of four repetitions of `s_{k-1}`. We first determine into which repetition the `n`th symbol falls, and what is the number `n'` of our symbol within this repetition. For `n=10` and `k=2` we have 10th symbol in `s_2` is the 2nd symbol in 3rd repetition of `s_1`.... to be continued

Comment: ...so `n'=2` and we also remember that `r=3` the repetition number. Now we need to know what is the `n'`th symbol in `s_{k-1}`. We do this by a recursive call: `b=f(n',k-1)`. And finally we check our `r` and if it is 2 or 3 we invert `b`. And `b` is the answer.

Comment: I managed to implement a solution http://pastebin.com/d6UypBim. I did it in c++ this time. I am not very good at algorithms analysis, so is this the solution that you were describing? Is this solution ok? I have tested it and it seems to work properly.

Comment: Also, is this the way you visualize the problem https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1BlTon9V51angsNXnY0Lmf1yLkRfiEIq6v1854BxyqGs/edit?usp=sharing ?

Comment: @cristid9, the picture looks correct, though it is just the visualization of the definition. As for your code, it looks sensible on first sight. You can test it extensively by comparing it with your slow code for, say, first 1000 digits (or even for first 1000000 digits, as you will need to run your slow code only once).

Answer (score 1):

The digits up to 4^k are used to determine the digts up to 4^(k+1). This suggests writing n in base 4.

Consider the binary expansion of n where we pair digits together, or equivalently the base 4 expansion where we write 0=(00), 1=(01), 2=(10), and 3=(11).

Let f(n) = +1 if the nth digit is 1, and -1 if the nth digit is 2, where the sequence starts at index 0 so f(0)=1, f(1)=-1, f(2)-1, f(3)=1. This index is one lower than the index starting from 1 used to compute the examples in the question. The 0-based nth digit is (3-f(n))/2. If you start the indices at 1, the nth digit is (3-f(n-1))/2.

```
f((00)n) = f(n).
f((01)n) = -f(n).
f((10)n) = -f(n).
f((11)n) = f(n).
```

You can use these to compute f recursively, but since it is a back-recursion you might as well compute f iteratively. f(n) is (-1)^(binary weight of n) = (-1)^(sum of the binary digits of n).

See the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence).